# Use String From Fragment In MainActivity Intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have *SelectionFragment.java* that gets the Facebook ID of the current logged in user.

In *MainActivity.java*, I have an intent to start another activity.

I need to somehow get the Facebook ID from *SelectionFragment.java* to be useable in an intent in *MainActivity.java*.

In the fragment, the string to get the facebook id is "selection_user_id"

I tried this code, but "selection_user_id" is only accessible from the *SelectionFragment.java*

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("EXTRA_FACEBOOK_ID","selection_user_id");
                startActivity(i);
```

*MainActivity.java*'s layout.xml file just contains fragments, so I think that might be why I can't get the information I need.

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.androidhive.SelectionFragment"
      android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.androidhive.SplashFragment"
      android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment"
      android:id="@+id/userSettingsFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Do I need to use some sort of adapter to pass information from my fragment to my main activity?

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in your fragment to give out the string. Like:

```
public String getSelectionUserId() { return selection_user_id; }
```

Then in your MainActivity:

```
SelectionFragment selectionFragment = (SelectionFragment)findViewById(R.id.selectionFragment);
String selectionUserId = selectionFragment.getSelectionUserId();
```

OR

in your fragment:

```
public static String selection_user_id;
```

In your MainActivity:

```
String selectionUserId = SelectionFragment.selection_user_id;
```

Comment: I tried these options and I couldn't get it to work. I just posted a new question with more details.